# Magento 1 : Customers can't login, cookie issue

Tags: magento-1.9, login, cookie

Some customers report that they can't log in on the frontend, even with a correct password. I've seen it happen sometimes, the page just reloads with no error messages.
Deleting the cookies solves the problem, but as you can guess I can't ask to do that to everyone.

*`My current Session Cookie Management settings are:`*

```
Cookie lifetime: 86400
Cookie path: /
Cookie domain: .domain.com
Use HTTP Only: Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Any tips?

Comment: Are you using any cache extension like "turpentine"?

Comment: Yes indeed I am, Varnish (Cachewall) + Turpentine. Any settings to change on it?

Comment: if any answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tickmark for right ansewer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

At Magento configuration at turpentine caching options, there is an option **"Normalise host".You have to enable it.**.

Thats it! After this no messy thing no double frontend cookies!

Also check: [solution](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/pull/832/files/006c1ceac20fe91915ef37e2c96bf77819305f89#r33774105)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Found it, although there's a warning that says: "Force requests to be for a specific domain name, will probably break most multi-store setups". Which is exactly my case, I have a multistore setup.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/222
And https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/169 it will hep you more.

Comment: I have added solution link to my answer. check that one also, and let me know if it will help you. thanks

Comment: Those links seem very helpful, thanks. The solution you linked seem to have been merged in Turpentine since 2015 already, yet I still have the issue. I will try to edit the .vcl config as suggested here: https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/222#issuecomment-110048136

Comment: if any answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya, where is this setting in magento, I can't find it